# How to convert "object" columns to "datetime" and keep NaNs as-is

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert these "object' columns to "datetime"

[image]

I've tried this

```
dashboard[['started_at_ahc', 'ended_at_ahc']] = dashboard[['started_at_ahc', 'ended_at_ahc']].apply(pd.to_datetime, erros="coerce")
```

I want to keep nan values as nan, but the code above converted the nans to `Sep 21, 1677 2:17 AM`. How can I fix that error; I mean to convert the object to datetime but in the same time keep the nans as nans.

[image]

Comment: post the data as text

Comment: @deadshot you mean to remove the images?

Comment: if some want to answer they need the data they can't copy from images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem simply was in Streamlit itself. After conversion, I used the command `st.write(dashboard[['date_of_birth', 'started_at_ahc', 'ended_at_ahc']])` which fill each `NaT` value to an initial date I think Streamlit developers use as a default value with NaT values. While using the same logic and also tried your solution @Ismael EL ATIFI in Jupyter Notebook, the results were okay and everything is correct. The problem is only with Streamlit. I've posted an [issue](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/dates-in-streamlit/5246) and waiting for a reply

Answer (score 0):

Pass `errors='ignore'` to the `to_datetime` function.

[image]

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Nothing happens. Same issue

Comment: @NemraKhalil you need to pass the errors parameter to the to_datetime function (not done in the code you provide). Try this :
dashboard[['started_at_ahc', 'ended_at_ahc']] = dashboard[['started_at_ahc', 'ended_at_ahc']].apply(lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, errors="ignore"))